# Python errno 13 permission error when reading windows 10 registry hive

Tags: python, windows

I have a simple python script that tries to read the content of a HIVE inside C:\Windows\System32\config. I have given full control on the directory to the user running the script.

[image]

I keep getting permission error.

[image]

Comment: can you provide the code inside hiv_read? Edit: Also did you try running the terminal ( command prompt) as an Administrator?

Comment: It looks like `SOFTWARE` is a folder, not a file.  Why are you calling `open()` on a folder?

Comment: @NULL yes I did, couple times.

Comment: @JohnGordon SOFTWARE is not a directory. It is a binary file.